# remove test database when tests ends (Symfony / PHP Unit)

Tags: symfony, testing, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am using **PHPUnit (9.5)** with **Symfony (5.3)**.

For my tests, I use the default test database config from **config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml** :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
        dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'
```

So my tests use the same database as prod with the suffix '_test'.

I added some code to **tests/bootstrap.php** to automate database creation / reset before each test runs :

```
// delete database if exists, then create
passthru('php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --env=test --force --if-exists');
passthru('php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test');

// run migrations
passthru('php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=test -n');
```

and I use **dama/doctrine-test-bundle** for automatic transactions for each tests.

That is working very well, but I have a question :

**Is there a way to delete the database at the end of test run ? (like I did in bootstrap.php)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your bootstrap.php file is running before the test, you need a solution to launch something after your test.

First, [create a command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#creating-a-command) that drop the test database.

In anyway, be very careful that the code in your command stop all execution, if you aren't in an explicit test environment (because it means you are in a production environment).

Then, you can alter your composer.json file to launch the created command after your test in a [chain of scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts).

Here is an exemple

```json
    "scripts": {
        "test-and-remove": [
            "@putenv APP_ENV=test",
            "phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml",
            "php bin/console app:drop-test-database"
        ],
```

Then you only have to launch your test via this new command:

```sh
composer test-and-remove
```

Comment: thanks, but I have already done this in bootstrap.php. This code run at the beginning of the tests, I need to have this code run at the end of the tests.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. I updated my answer. I hope it will help you